# WKWebView not loading URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am trying to get WKWebView working, but it just won't load my URL. It loads https://apple.com, but no other URL.

This is the code I have in my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }}
```

I have added this to my info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>google.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

But it's not showing anything in my app. I have added the WKWebView to main storyboard as well.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try implementing some of the relevant delegate methods and see if there is any error.

Comment: Do you see any output in the console in XCode? If there are security issues, you should see a warning or other output.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors. It's just blank.

Comment: Hmm, I have just tested it using another of my sites on a different server, and that has worked first time. I will have to look to see if I am blocking frames for whatever reason. The site I have it working with is a http://, the one I can't get working is a https:// wonder if that is the issue.